# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2', linux

Tags: linux, opencv

i got this opencv issue:

when downloading i got the message "already satisfied"

when i want to use it i get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'"

what could the problem be?

```css
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (4.5.1.48)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.2)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.8.4 (default, Sep 16 2020, 00:40:58) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Comment: try `python -m pip install opencv-python` and check if it works

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7` vs `Python 3.8.4` -- looks like you installed it for a different interpreter than the one you're trying to use.